# sql normalize a table

Tags: sql

I have a table called service entry. In a service entry there could be multiple parts. So the table service entry part will have a row for each part.  The parts are stored in the part table. The service entry table has a comma delimeted column which contains the parts info used for display on the page.

Dbo.Part

```
ID   PartDescription
270  Syringe assembly
282  LPH pcb 
287  Valve block assembly
```

**Dbo.ServiceEntry**

```
ServiceEntryID, Description
     1200         270 ~ Syringe assembly  ~ 7,3 ~ Increase drive current from 3 --> 1.|282 ~ LPH pcb ~ 8 ~  | 287 ~ Valve block
   assembly ~ null ~
```

In the above here is the structure for the column:

```
PartID ~ PartDescription ~ ServiceType ~ Comment
```

For multiple parts, this character `|` is added and the structure is repeated.

**`ServiceEntryPart`:**

```
ID  ServiceEntryID   PartID  ServiceTypev Comment
1    1200            270      7,3         Increase drive current from 3
2    1200            282      8          
3    1200            287      null
```

**QUESTION**

Dbo.Part

```
ID   PartDescription       OldID
331  Syringe assembly      270
335  LPH pcb               282
336  Valve block assembly  287
```

So if you look at the above part table whats happening is that the Part Table is being updated. New parts will be added and for existing parts their ids will be updated to new ids and also there could be new part descriptions. As you could see, the service entry table with the column part description will not be in sync for the service entry which was created before. What I am trying to do is to update existing service entry part table with the new part ids and their dcescriptions and finally update column called part description in the service entry table. Updating the service entry part table is simple but the problem is how do i update the delimeted column in the service entry table.

Comment: You appear to be doing well so far.  I don't see an actual question though.

Comment: sorry, the question is towards the end, just need some help with the SQL to update the table for instance see the desired data. thanks

Comment: `So essentialy for the sake of normalization...` Don't you mean for the sake of de-normalization? In a normalized database, the part description would appear in the Parts table, and only the PartId would appear in other tables.

Comment: will a partID have the same partDescription across ServiceEntryIDs?  This would be a lot easier if you could create a part table with the ID and description.

Comment: Beth I have a part table. The thing is im changing the parts with new parts okay.  Existing parts will be replaced with new ones meaning new part ids and part descriptions. As you could see the service entry records which was create before will not be insync with the new parts right. So im trying to figure out a way to update that column if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're working with columns that contain multiple, delimited values (like the PICK database) :

```
`For multiple parts, this character | is added and the structure is repeated.`
```

Typically, in a normalized database, one would have:

```
UNIT  (something that might need service or repair)
UnitId  PK
UnitDescription

PARTS  (repair / replacement parts)
PartId PK
PartDescription

UNIT_SERVICES  (instances of repair visits/ service)
ServiceID   int primary key
UnitId      foreign key references UNIT
ServiceDate
TechnicianID
etc


SERVICE_PART   (part used in the service)
ID          primary key
ServiceID   foreign key references SERVICE
PartID      foreign key references PART
Quantity
```

There could be zero, one, or multiple UNIT_SERVICES associated with a UNIT.
There could be zero, one, or multiple SERVICE_PARTS associated with a SERVICE.

In a normalized database,  each part used in the servicing of a unit would exist in its own row in the SERVICE_PART table.  We would not find two or more parts in the same SERVICE_PART tuple, separated by some delimiter, as was commonly done in so-called multivalued databases, which were precursors to the modern OODBMS.

Comment: Service entry has 1:many relationship with the service entry part table. In one service entry there could be multiple parts. So if there are multiple parts in a service entry, the service entry part table will have multiple service entry part rows and each row containing the individual part information. The issue is, I am trying to update my parts with new parts meaning existing parts will have new ids instead of old ids and existing part description will have new part descriptions. So you could see, the service entry record which was created before needs to updated with the new part info.

Comment: I updated the question. Apologies. It should be much clearer now.

Comment: `I am trying to update my parts with new parts...existing parts will have new ids.` That too is not the normalized way, but you can do it as follows: add some new columns:  newid, newdescription to both your Parts master table and your child tables.  Then update the child tables with the new values from the master table, joining on OLD id. Drop all FK constraints. Drop the old columns. Recreate new FK constraints.   Your problem is the RESULT of a denormalized approach. Ids should never change! Cardinal rule. Part code that can change is worthless candidate for primary key.

Comment: Cool, I will add the columns, its just how do i update that delimeted column in the service entry table. It seems painful to do

Comment: `...it seems painful to do`.  Correct.

Comment: You must split the string on the delimeter and create one row for each delimited chunk. You cannot work with delimited multivalues like that in SQL.

Comment: True, I am just going to update that value with some c#, sql is a little difficult for these operations. Thanks for your help buddy!